# Will the Ubuntu Edge work in countries without LTE?

Tags: 3g, ubuntu-edge

I live in a country with no LTE, we use 3G. Will the Edge still work here?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Laurent! Ubuntu Edge was a crowdfunded project that, unfortunately, didn't meet its funding goal. Therefore, the phone will not be manufactured, and so your question is off-topic. Read more about Ubuntu Edge [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Edge).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

From the Ubuntu Edge project page...

> The Ubuntu Edge is an open device, not locked to any particular network. It works in all countries that provide GSM/3G/LTE-based network services. It will also support the two LTE standards to provide 4G mobile broadband connectivity around the world